# manipulate clicked link in WebView Android

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I have WebView in my android application with loaded local page where I have PDF links looks like:

```
    <a href="pdf:DOCUMENT.pdf">DOCUMENT</a>
```

My need is to when user will click on this link change the url and redirect user to "http://URL/pdf_files/DOCUMENT.pdf". My code is not working. I've search a lot of information and tried a lot.

My code below:

```
    webview = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webview);

    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

    webview.loadURL("files://assets/localpage.html");

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        String[] file_name = url.split(":");
        url = "http://URL/pdf_files/"+file_name[1];
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
      }
    });
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your file is stored in local file system use file://URL/pdf_files/ 
this may solve your problem